# Issues performing URL Rewrite using Python's Requests library

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

I'm trying to use Requests to proxy requests sent to a Flask endpoint to another URL.

I want to pass on any data that's posted, so I use `json=get_json()` in `requests.post`. However, when the initial request is GET, it doesn't have any JSON, so I get a 400 error with "Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)".

I tried `json=request.data` instead, but I get "TypeError: Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable".

How can I get the data without assuming it's JSON? How can I pass the data to Requests without assuming it's JSON?

```
from flask import request
import requests

@app.route("/pas/<path:arg>", methods=("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"))
def proxy(arg):
    url = f"http://{config.pasUrl}:{config.pasPort}/{arg}?{request.query_string.decode('utf-8')}"
    out_request = requests.request(
        method=request.method,
        url=url,
        headers=request.headers,
        json=request.get_json(),
    )
    return out_request.text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `json=request.get_json()` with `data=request.get_data()`.

The `data` parameter of `requests.request()` [takes a dictionary, list of tuples, bytes, or file-like object](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/), and Flask's `request.get_data()` returns the raw bytes of the body of the request.